# How can I get list of classes already loaded into memory in specific bundle (or binary)?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

It's possible to get list of classes from a bundle via `NSBundleDidLoadNotification`. But I can't figure out how I can get them from already loaded bundle. (same bundle with code)

I'm trying to get class list of my application bundle. More specifically, the classes only in my application binary.

I looked at `objc_getClassList`, but it returns *ALL* classes and it's obviously too heavy for me. I need lightweight method. I found `objc_copyClassNamesForImage` by googling, but it's not documented, and I don't know how to use it *safely*. I think I can try to use it conventionally, but I want to find another more safe option before going there.

Comment: Can you define the problem space a little more?  Are you trying to get a list of classes in bundles already loaded by the application itself or something else?

Comment: @Chris I'm trying to get class list defined in application binary itself. I modified my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you reviewed the following documentation? http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately, it doesn't look offering features required for me.

Comment: Interesting.  I thought the "Searching for Related Bundles" section which spoke about calling allBundles to return an array of all of the application's non-framework bundles should do it...

Comment: @Chris It offers only bundles listing, not about classes.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to iterate through all the classes registered with the runtime and use `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` on each one to figure out which one it came from.  You can then sort things into sets based on the result.

Something like this:

```
@interface NSBundle (DDAdditions)

- (NSArray *)definedClasses_dd;

@end

@implementation NSBundle (DDAdditions)

- (NSArray *)definedClasses_dd {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

    int numberOfClasses = objc_getClassList(NULL, 0);
    Class *classes = calloc(sizeof(Class), numberOfClasses);
    numberOfClasses = objc_getClassList(classes, numberOfClasses);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfClasses; ++i) {
        Class c = classes[i];
        if ([NSBundle bundleForClass:c] == self) {
            [array addObject:c];
        }
    }
    free(classes);
    return array;
}

@end
```

Then you can call:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] definedClasses_dd]);
```

Comment: It looks gathering all of classes currently loaded in system. Should I consider performance when using it?

Comment: @Eonil sure you can consider performance. Since this is for iOS, you won't be loading other bundles, so you could modify this code to build arrays for every bundle it finds and then caches those arrays as static info.  Then the `definedClasses` method would simply access that cache (or create it if necessary).

Comment: You missed the point, when he said he wanted to achieve it in a non-heavy way; he was specifically referring to the heavy objc_getClassList method that you use first then filter. It returns 6000 classes by the way.

Answer (score 5):

Try this magic:

```
- (NSArray *)getClassNames {
    NSMutableArray *classNames = [NSMutableArray array];
    unsigned int count = 0;
    const char **classes = objc_copyClassNamesForImage([[[NSBundle mainBundle] executablePath] UTF8String], &count);
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<count;i++){
        NSString *className = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:classes[i]];
        [classNames addObject:className];
    }
    return classNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I could find some example for the function `objc_copyClassNamesForImage` at here.

http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/test/weak.m

```
// class name list
const char *image = class_getImageName(objc_getClass("NotMissingRoot"));
testassert(image);
const char **names = objc_copyClassNamesForImage(image, NULL);
testassert(names);
testassert(classInNameList(names, "NotMissingRoot"));
testassert(classInNameList(names, "NotMissingSuper"));
if (weakMissing) {
    testassert(! classInNameList(names, "MissingRoot"));
    testassert(! classInNameList(names, "MissingSuper"));
} else {
    testassert(classInNameList(names, "MissingRoot"));
    testassert(classInNameList(names, "MissingSuper"));
}
free(names);
```

The source code is unofficial but from Apple. So I decided to use this code until I find any better way.